# How to save addTo in order by given date/id?

Tags: grails

I need some help on my API, when I'm on web, the order is saving correct, but when its on API, it goes all wrong:

```
def test = parseJSON.sort { a, b -> a.ID <=> b.ID } //or dateTime, will print the same
//order when I print each of them
[IDWeb:0, conductivity:0, ReportId:2, dissolvedOxygen:0, levelWater:1, ID:1, ph:0, redoxPotential:0, temperature:0]
[IDWeb:0, conductivity:0, ReportId:2, dissolvedOxygen:0, levelWater:0, ID:2, ph:0, redoxPotential:0, temperature:0]
[IDWeb:0, conductivity:0, ReportId:2, dissolvedOxygen:0, levelWater:0, ID:3, ph:0, redoxPotential:0, temperature:0]
[IDWeb:0, conductivity:0, ReportId:2, dissolvedOxygen:0, levelWater:4, ID:4, ph:0, redoxPotential:0, temperature:0]

    test.each{
        def sample = new SampleWater()
        sample.levelWater = it.levelWater
        sample.conductivity = it.conductivity
        sample.dissolvedOxygen = it.dissolvedOxygen
        sample.redoxPotential = it.redoxPotential
        sample.ph = it.ph
        sample.temperature = it.temperature
        water.addToSamples(sample)
    }
    return water
```

My problem is that `addTo` is not saving in order. How can I solve this?

Comment: what is the relation between water and samplewater domains. are you using a list or set?

Comment: water hasmany sample and sample belongs to water. and im using a list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you have defined the type of samples as a `List` in your `Water` domain class so that we can maintain the insertion order:

```
class Water {

    static hasMany = [samples: Sample]

    List<Sample> samples = []
}

class Sample {

    def levelWater
}
```

By default implementation of `hasMany` is of type `Set` which does not maintain the insertion order but is responsible for uniqueness.

Since, now you samples will be saved in the same order as they are inserted.

Answer (score 0):

You have to specify with order you want to apply to the list of SampleWater in the "water" domain class.
i.e:

```
class BlogCategory {

    static hasMany = [
        entries : BlogEntry
    ]   

    static mapping = {
        entries: sort:'dateCreated', order:'desc'
    }
}
```

In this example  BlogEntry will be ordered  respect `dateCreated`.